# How can I migrate my backups of my iPhone to my local drive?

Tags: icloud, backup

My iCloud is almost full and there are a couple of iPhone backups that are hogging pretty much data. How can I save these backups to my local drive? I cannot see them in iCloud Drive on my Mac...

Answer (score 2):

You can't move the content of an iCloud Backup to your computer. What you can do instead:

- Disable iCloud backup on your iPhone
- Use your computer to backup the phone (requires a wired connection)

See https://support.apple.com/HT204136 for details on how to set this up.

Comment: I'd recommend doing those in the opposite order. Make sure you have the local backup first, then disable and delete the online backup. (I'm assuming there's no Apple thing that makes it where you can't have both online and offline backups at the same time).

Comment: @trlkly If you can explain how to do this, step-by-step with screenshots etc, this would make a good answer.

Comment: I dont have the phone in that state. I want to keep that specific backup...